# Automatically schema backup in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I am working with an Oracle Database and I have a user (called XY) with permissions R/W. I would like to to do automatic backups of the user schema XY. I don't own the server and I don't know if the provider does backup of my schema. Probably does,but I would like to do myself the automatic Backup. I use as Oracle Client the tool SQL Developer.

I know that I can do **Extras-> Database Copy** but it is not automatic.

Can I achieve this with this client? If so, how?If it is not possible, what alternative do I have?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the server's filesystem? In that case you can use `dbms_datapump` to create a schema dump.

Comment: As far as I know I have not acces to server's filesystem. The provider is an external company and we have only one user in its Oracle Database with R/W permissions. For the other user schemas our user has just read permissions. I have created in my user schema only two tables and currently I do the backups of these tables manually (copy table).I want just to define an automatic job that does that for me every day.

Comment: Do I should use RMAN?

Comment: You need local access to use rman.

Comment: old fashioned `exp/imp`

Comment: hi ivan,but can I schedule a job that works automatic to export a schema?

Answer (score 3):

If you will have access to server's filesystem, or you can ask for this, you can use **crontab** utility. To verify whether you have access to cron, type in the following

```
crontab -e
```

If you will have an OS user,and if you can use the crontab utility to schedule a job, you can try something like this:

```
*/30 * * * * ~/bin/dump.bsh 1>~/bin/log/dump.log 2>&1
```

This simple entry make a logical backup every half hour.
The dump.bsh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
. $HOME/.bash_profile

now=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M"`
expdp user/passwd directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=lbackup$now.dmp schemas=schema_to_backup
```

You need to set Oracle env variables (here in the .bash_profile) since **cron** passes only a minimal set of env variables to your jobs.

Otherwise, go and have a look at [this](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-developer-31-data-pump-wizards.php) SQL Developer page. In the **exports** (**expdp**) section there is also a reference to automatic jobs.